# can't prevent NAs for empty cells in factor columns using readr

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read file with some empty cells and getting for empty cells an expected `NA`.
I have some special columns which can only have the values `''` or `'+'`. So I would like to set these columns to a factor class by using

```
read_tsv('file.txt', 
         col_types=list(
             column_with_empty_cells=col_factor(c('','+'))))
```

But the column still has `NAs` in these columns. I could change the global behaviour of the `readr_tsv` function by changing the `na` parameter, but this is not what I want. I want to change this only in specific columns.

Is there a way to convert these `NAs` directly to `''`? I could do this afterwards for sure, but I am wondering if I am using the thing in the wrong way.

**EDIT**
Here is a [test file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38610859/file.txt)

How do I actually upload a file? I could only attach images...

Comment: try passing `na = character()`

Comment: Hm, so `readr::col_factor(c('','+'), na=character())` gives me a `unused argument` error...

Comment: `col_factor(c('','+'), na=character())` does not give me an `unused argument` error, but it still does not do what you want `df <- read_tsv('file.txt', 
               na = character(),
               col_types = list(
                 column_with_empty_cells=col_factor(c('','+')))
              )
`

Comment: Btw, my code above gives me this object `Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 28 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ test                   : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
 $ column_with_empty_cells: Factor w/ 2 levels "","+": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...`  From reading your question this still does not sound like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a new function to solve this issue using `lapply` and `factor`:

```
library(readr)

read_tsv2 <- function(file, na.char=" "){
  test <- read_tsv(file = file, col_types=list(column_with_empty_cells=col_character()))
  test <- as.data.frame(test)
  names_tsv <- names(test)
  test <- lapply(test,
         function(x){
    if(sum(is.na(x))!=length(x)){
      x[is.na(x)] <- na.char 
    factor(x,levels = unique(x))
    }else{
      x
    }
  }
  )
  test <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, test)
  names(test) <- names_tsv
  test
}

file <- read_tsv2(file = "~/Downloads/file.txt", na.char = " ")

file

   test column_with_empty_cells
1  <NA>                        
2  <NA>                        
3  <NA>                        
4  <NA>                        
5  <NA>                        
6  <NA>                        
7  <NA>                        
8  <NA>                        
9  <NA>                        
10 <NA>                        
11 <NA>                        
12 <NA>                        
13 <NA>                        
14 <NA>                        
15 <NA>                        
16 <NA>                        
17 <NA>                        
18 <NA>                        
19 <NA>                        
20 <NA>                        
21 <NA>                        
22 <NA>                        
23 <NA>                        
24 <NA>                       +
25 <NA>                       +
26 <NA>                        
27 <NA>                        
28 <NA>                       +
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation for `readr`, there isn't an implementation for passing multiple na arguments for subsets of columns, only a global specification. I assume that this would be most salient when computational efficiency is necessary. For those instances, it might be worth it to do multiple calls to `read_tsv` specifying the subset of columns to read with an na argument specification and skip all other columns. Then repeat the process for the other subset of columns with the different na argument and read only the columns which should be parsed with that na argument. Lastly, one can could `cbind` the multiple data frames.

This issue has not been raised with the `readr` developers. If you wish to submit it as an enhancement feel free to do so by generating a new issue at the project's repository: [Readr](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr).

Answer (score 0):

`read_tsv` is a custom implementation of `read_delim` and so is `read_csv`. The `tsv` is designed specifically to read tab separated files, which in this case is also your test file. You can solve your problem easily by using `read_csv` if you are not tied to using the specific tab separated implementation.

`read_csv` will by default take the class as factor if it finds few unique character set in a column.

To get the values **as factor**

```
read.csv("test.txt", sep = "\t")
```

To get the values **as character**

```
read.csv("test.txt", sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

[Sample dataframe read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFcgo.png)

**EDIT 1**

if you want specific columns with `" "` to be treated as `NA`, you can pass the class using lappy only to those column list at the time of reading, however based on your question, it looks like you want `NULL` to be treated as NA and any other character should not be coerced.